# Meaning of the word "conjugate" across mathematics?

Tags: definition, math-history

Clearly, the word *conjugate* or *conjugation* is used for a myriad of different concepts across mathematics and even in science (see the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugation)).

Its meaning can range from the fraction used to rationalize a denominator in pre-algebra, to the $gNg^{-1}$ action in group theory. Complex numbers have conjugates, and harmonic functions can have “harmonic conjugates”.

Surprisingly, I can’t find an explanation of the origin of the word “conjugate” to describe all these cases, nor an explicit meaning or mathematical definition of the word itself.

What is the history of this word, and what (if any) unifying concepts tie the examples together?

Answer (score 8):

The word, simply put, means "coupled". In Spanish, you have the word "cónyuge" for the husband or wife of a person. Here we usually have a certain concept (the conjugates of a root, the harmonic conjugate), or operation (elements in the same orbit of an action) and we like to identify elements related under this concept.

I wouldn't think there is a unifying (mathematical concept) that tie these examples together. At least, I wouldn't bet on it.

Comment: There is also "conjugal relations" in English.

Comment: @SuzuHirose Indeed.

Comment: It comes from the Latin conjux, giving rise to the stem conjug- which means spouse.

Comment: If there's a unifying concept, it's "operations with order 2".

Comment: Now try to compare it with the word "dual".

Comment: @ChasBrown Not really.  Conjugate subgroups come in collections larger than 2, as do Galois conjugates.  Using "conjugate" in this way is reasonable since it declares that any two elements from the collection are conjugate.  But there is no operation of order 2.